# How to remove concrete lines from a text file depending on whether there is a certain character

Tags: python, text-files

How can I delete lines in a text file that contain a specific line?

I'm trying to delete lines where there are no characters> = and <

example

input:

```
>=3 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
<=2 1 2 3 4
```

required output:

```
>=3 1 2 3
<=2 1 2 3 4
```

I tried it like this but it doesn't work as I imagined

```
with open("demofile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "<":
            print(line)
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this if

```
        if line.strip("\n") != "<":
```

to

```
        if any(desired_char in line for desired_char in ("<", ">", "=")):
```

This way you will keep the lines that contain `any` of the `("<", ">", "=")`.